# Несколько if и else

Tags: python, if

Есть функция, в которой много `if`ов. Я хочу добавить `else`, чтобы возвращаться в начало функции. Но, как я понимаю, если сразу после конструкции `if` я напишу `else`, то код будет отделен от другой части.

```py
    def func():
        while True:
            parseresult = requests.get('https://market.csgo.com/api/v2/trade-request-give-p2p?key=' + marketkey).json()
            time.sleep(1)
            if parseresult['success'] == True:
                resultfrommarket = requests.get('https://market.csgo.com/api/v2/trade-request-give-p2p?key=' + marketkey).json()
                time.sleep(1)
                resultfromsteam = requests.get("http://api.steampowered.com/IEconService/GetTradeOffers/v1/?key=" + api + "&get_sent_offers=1&active_only=1").json()
                time.sleep(1)
                xx = resultfromsteam.get('response')
                if parseresult['success'] == True:
                    if xx != {}:
                        trade_id = resultfromsteam["response"]["trade_offers_sent"][0]["tradeofferid"]
                        resultion = resultfrommarket.get('success')
                        if resultion != False:
                        else:
                            func():

                            if resultfrommarket["offer"]["tradeoffermessage"] == resultfromsteam["response"]["trade_offers_sent"][0]["message"]:
                                partnerfrommarket = resultfrommarket['offer']['partner']
```

Все `if`ы нужны.

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "вернуться в начало функции" и под "отделен", какая-то немного непонятная формулировка?

Comment: Есть инструкция `continue`...

Comment: И второй `if parseresult['success'] == True:` скорее всего не нужен, потому что после первого такого вызова он не изменился и внутри первого `if` всегда будет таким же. К тому же у вас вечный цикл, который вы потом в одном из `else` вызываете второй раз.

Comment: + скорее всего ваш код не запустится из-за странной конструкции `if-else`, между `if` и `else` поставьте хотя бы `pass`. А лучше измените условие и избавьтесь `else`.

Comment: Я описал выше,что все нужно.

Comment: Здесь есть явные синтаксические и смысловые ошибки

Comment: *сразу после конструкции if я напишу else то код будет отделен от другой части* от какой другой части? каким образом отделён?

Comment: господа отвечающие на вопросы, предлагаю закрыть данный вопрос с формулировкой `"непонятна суть вопроса"`, в надежде, что это поможет автору научиться более внятно формулировать вопросы...

Comment: ``if parseresult['success'] == True`` - масло масляное. ``if parseresult['success']`` достаточно.

Comment: @MaxU, да вроде вполне понятно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а как вы поняли `"то код будет отделен от другой части"` ?

Comment: @MaxU, как то, что в языках else относится к ближайшему if (не совсем питонный случай, но суть та же - он уже внутри else, значит двигать else влево он не может). А он хочет прервать всю ветку, чтобы последующий код не выполнялся. Я предполагаю, что ему нужен continue, о чём и написал в ответе.

Answer (score 3):

Возможно подойдёт такое:

```
while True:
  ...
    ...
      ...
        if ...
          ...
        else:
          continue
```

Comment: ++ за умение читать мысли )

Comment: а я думал if-elif-else

Comment: @Victor, вроде к коду в вопросу elif не подходит?

Comment: Да , не подходит.Но теоретически можно поменяться вложенности на elif ,просто я не знаю что за csgo.com